# How to form a new list except the strings?

Tags: python

I have a list:

```
data = ["45", "56", "75", "ABC", "32"]
```

I would like this to be the output:

```
data_new=[45,56,75,32]
```

Comment: Hello! Please try something on your own and tell us what went wrong.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I tried data_new=[int (i) for i in data if i.isdigit], then produced an error :invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'ABC'

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
data_new = [int(x) for x in data if x.isdigit()]
```

Comment: thank you. I am confuse about the difference between isdigit() and isdigit without the bracket

Comment: @StarBright `isdigit` is the function, `isdigit()` is the result, a boolean value

Answer (score 1):

Here is the full loop solution:

```
data_new = []
for i in data:
    if i.isdigit():
        i = int(i)
        data_new.append(i)
```

What is happening is you are looping through all the items in data, you check each item to see if it [`isdigit()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isdigit). From there you convert that item now to a `int` from a `str`, that new item gets appended to `data_new`

Shorter methods are available with the use of [`map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) and [`filter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter) or [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)

```
data_new = list(map(int, filter(lambda x: x.isdigit(), data)))

data_new = [int(i) for i in data if i.isdigit()]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code:

```
data_new = []
for i in data:
    if i.is_numeric():
        data_new.append(int(i))
```

Comment: what are you mapping this function to? You forgot an argument

Comment: Edit answer, sry

Comment: @Aran-Fey Edit by your issue